# Slow Download Speed on Windows LocalHost

Tags: php, windows, performance, localhost

I installed localhost (xammp, wampserver) on a VDS.  When I try to get a file using PHP Curl and file_get_contents, the download speed is very low. I can download a 100mb file in 10 minutes. If I try to download the same file with a browser, the duration is only 3 seconds. What can be the reason?
Thanks for your interest.

Comment: you can see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937188/curl-really-slow)

Answer (score -1):

Downloading content at a specific URL is common practice on the internet, especially due to increased usage of web services and APIs offered by Amazon, Alexa, Digg, etc. PHP's cURL library, which often comes with default shared hosting configurations, allows web developers to complete this task.

## u can try

```
/* gets the data from a URL */
function get_data($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}
```

## The Usage

$returned_content = get_data('http://davidwalsh.name'); //something like  this

Alternatively, you can use the file_get_contents function remotely, but many hosts don't allow this.

Comment: Those are actually what I tried, and get low download speed, is there any other solution? Or what can be the reason of the slow speed? Thanks

Comment: Check if you have correct nameserver entries in /etc/resolv.conf
Sometimes slow nameservers affect data transfer speed