# Slow cURL in PHP, fast in shell

Tags: php, curl

The following PHP code works very slow, download speed is extremely low:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://foo.net/file.xml');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'cURL');

$response = curl_exec($curl);

print_r(curl_getinfo($curl));

print_r([
    'errno' => curl_errno($curl),
    'error' => curl_error($curl),
]);
```

The result:

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://foo.net/file.xml
    [content_type] => text/xml
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 275
    [request_size] => 120
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 180.055349
    [namelookup_time] => 0.124831
    [connect_time] => 0.163125
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.571803
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 14892781
    [speed_download] => 82712
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 55369333
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.686118
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => y.y.y.y
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 443
    [local_ip] => x.x.x.x
    [local_port] => 50579
)
Array
(
    [errno] => 28
    [error] => Operation timed out after 180055 milliseconds with 14892781 out of 55369333 bytes received
)
```

But cURL in shell downloads much faster:

```
# curl -O -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" https://foo.net/file.xml
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 52.8M  100 52.8M    0     0  1461k      0  0:00:36  0:00:36 --:--:-- 1421k
```

What can be the reason for cURL to perfom in such manner when called from PHP?

Comment: Check for errors in your PHP code.

Comment: There are no errors in PHP code, everything works but very slow.

Comment: I've found something here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1937188/curl-really-slow maybe this can help?

Comment: We can reduce the possibilities by doing a simple profiling for each statement in the php code, something like this might be enough to spot the bottle neck `$lastTime = time(); /*stmt 1;*/  echo time() - $lastTime; /*stmt 2;*/ ` .

Comment: Guys, the only problem is a slow working curl in php, nothing else. There are no errors in code, no need to use profiling, everything needed you can see in speed_download of curl_get_info.

Comment: Just a wild idea, but you could try setting the same User-Agent as the one your browser is using.

Comment: No changes. Bug is in how curl in php works with gzip encoding, cpu usage jumps to 100% when download is in progress. Console curl with gzip works at the same speed as php with curl without gzip.

Comment: Have you ever found the cause? We seem to have a very similar situation here.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution for this?